# BASIC Stamp and external speaker

Tags: microcontroller, speakers

How to connect a real external speaker through a classic Jack connecter to the [Board of Education](http://www.parallax.com/Store/Microcontrollers/BASICStampProgrammingKits/tabid/136/ProductID/294/List/0/Default.aspx?SortField=ProductName,ProductName)?

So that I can send it FREQOUT instructions?

(instead of using the piezo-electric component)

Answer (score 1):

I've not used this board before. But, I assume you could wire the existing piezo sounder to a simple amplifier and onto your speaker. An [LM386](http://web.mit.edu/6.s28/www/schematics/lm386.htm) would be ideal.

Comment: I finally used a broken Jack wire : and it worked!

Comment: Is this question now closed? If so, please mark it as closed.